# C#: Using HTMLAgilityPack how to get a value inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am using HTMLAgilityPack. I want to get a value inside a script tag, see the code:

```
<div id="frmSeller" method="post" name="frmSeller">
<div class="clear"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Biz.Product.GroupItemSwitchLogic.init();
    Biz.Product.GroupItemSwitcher.init({
        properties:null,
        availableMap:[{"info":{"item":"28-200-            286","price":95.99,"vehicle":null},"map":[]}],
        selectedProperties:[]
        });
 </script>
 </div>
```

From there I want to get value of "price" that is 95.99.
How can i get this kindly tell me, what type of Regex I can use....
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can do some string manipulation like this

s = the html code

```
var s = z.Split(new String[] { @"price"":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var price = s[1].Split(',')[0];
```

and now price variable has your price

Comment: oh it works. thank you